Odoo how to refresh files (developer features) with docker-compose?
I setup Odoo to run with the development mode activated, but it doesn't work.
In their documentation they explain to simply add the arguments --dev all to allow the system to refresh itself after files are updated. Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file
service:
  web:
    image: odoo:18
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=myodoo
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo:ro
      - ./addons:/mnt/custom-addons:ro
      - ./enterprise:/mnt/enterprise-addons:ro
    command: --dev all -d test
  db:
    ...

Does anyone know how to refresh Odoo when python files are updated without restarting the server ?

change your command to: --dev=all

This doesn't work neither

what do you mean by refresh?

Every time a python source file is change the server should update itself. Same for the XML. I currently have to update the module for XML change and restart the server for python
